# Avoid devise validation flash message at root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

[I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap)

routes.rb

```
root :to => 'users#index'
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions"}
  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get '/users/sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get "/users/sign_up", :to => "registrations#new"
  end
```

When I try to access `localhost:3000`, I will directed to `localhost:3000/users/sign_in` and that's normal, because of `filter`, but however I will get a validation message

> You need to sign in or sign up before continuing

How to avoid this?

I tried changing by using `match` in routes that didn't help out.

**Edit:**
Consider a scenario:
(without user session) if I try to access /roles will be redirected to sign in path, at that point I would require msg. or I would loose other flash validations such as sign-out, email-exists, pwd wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell Application to use root as sessions#new if user not logged-in

> config/routes.rb

```
authenticated :user do
    root :to => "users#index"
  end
  unauthenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do
      get "/" => "devise/sessions#new"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest to do this is to pass an empty string to the devise.en.yml file inside config folder.Steps are as follows:

1. Pass a empty string in your devise.en.yml file config as:

   `en:
   devise:
     failure:
      unauthenticated: ''`
2. Then inside your layout show the flash messages only if flash hash does not have a blank value:
   `<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
     <%= content_tag :div, value, :class => "flash #{key}" unless value.blank? %>
   <% end %>`

Comment: You need to check if the request.path is equal to the devise sign in path '/users/sign_in' then we don't show the flash messages otherwise it will be shown for all other URL'
`<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, :class => "flash #{key}" unless request.path == '/users/sign_in %>
<% end %>`