# Rails - wrong number of arguments (:force => true?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a `before_filter` that usually validates every controller; however I dont use it for a certain controller. But, when I access a specific action from that controller, for some reason I get an error saying `Rails - wrong number of arguments (:force => true?)` for the authentication. I added a parameter in the method to see what was getting passed to the method and I saw this as a parameter `{:force=>true}`. This doesn't happen on any other controller actions.

Here is my error

```
ArgumentError in RegistrationsController#edit

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Rails.root: *

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `authenticate_user!'
```

Here is my the route I am trying to access

```
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                    registrations#edit
```

Here is my controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end

  def edit_password
  end
end
```

Here is the before_filter method

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

    def authenticate_user!
        unless signed_in?
            redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
        end
    end
end
```

Btw the route was provided to me by devise

Answer (score 4):

Filter is provided by `devise`, so don't try to bend it.

Use it in required `controllers`.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

If you are looking handle unauthenticated user, you can do this in your `routes` file

```
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "users#index"
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do
      get "/" => "sessions#new"
    end
  end
```

Hope below part is already set

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions"}
```

[copied from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083432/avoid-devise-validation-flash-message-at-root-path/24135199#24135199)